# Tcp: Public remote endpoint but private local endpoint?

Tags: c#, tcp

my situation looks like this: I forwarded the port 80 on my router, that is connected to the internet and linked it to my pc. On my pc i'm running a C# program (i use the class **HttpListener**) which logs every TCP connection that is going on. It prints the timestamp, remote endpoint and the local endpoint.

I expect that, when my **remote endpoint is a public** ip, then my **local endpoint is the public ip from my router**.

But in my log file i found this

62.143.189.207 (remote), 192.168.178.25 (local)

Can anyone tell, how is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your application is an http listener bound to a network interface on your PC.

All your NIC knows is your local ip address. It doesn’t actually know anything about the public facing address on your router.

When a request comes in, the router is performing the address translation, directing port 80 traffic to your PC and thusly returning traffic right back to the client.

Comment: But when i access my router from outside it shows a public ip and NOT my ip in the private network. This request in my upper example isn't from me. I have no idea why it is this way. I cannot reproduce this behavior.